# accessing github in powershell/terminal resolves to localhost

Tags: powershell, proxy, router, terminal, github

So I live in China and am using shadowsocksR on my router to bypass the Great firewall. Today when i try to update flutter using the powershell in VScode the powershell gives the error

"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080: Connection refused".

Seems like something make github resolve to localhost. Later I used both the terminal and powershell to ping google found out that they can't access any websites banned by the Great Firewall. So it seems like the proxy on my router failed to work. But the proxy does work on IE, Chrome, and any other devices that are connected to my router. The powershell and github was working fine like two weeks ago. Now I feel very desperate and thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you require a sox proxy in order to connect to github.  If you attempt to ping github,ccom, do you get a proper pub ip return or does it resolve to localhost?